# Setup a clear macro in Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am looking to setup a macro in Google Sheets and I am having issues. Below is my script:

```
function clearRange() {
//replace 'Sheet1'
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet1.getRange('D3:D46').clearContent();
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file
>   "Code")

Can any review this and let me know what I am not seeing here.

Comment: sheet1 has no value at line4, so it is not being set to anything on the previous line, which would suggest that either your sheet name is incorrect, or the code in line3 is bad

Answer (score 0):

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

found here

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)